# Downloading youtube video info

Tags: c#, format, protocols, webclient

I am trying to download response from this url

```
http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?html5=1&video_id=sFwcLC5HC9I
```

The file it returns can be downloaded from browser, but when I try to save it with c# webclient I get only error message.

> errorcode=180&status=fail&reason=HTTP+is+not+supported.

Is there any other way to download file from the API without using HTTP?

What have I tried (a is instance of WebClient):

```
byte[] policko = a.DownloadData("http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?html5=1&video_id=sFwcLC5HC9I");
a.DownloadFile("http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?html5=1&video_id=sFwcLC5HC9I", "filename");
a.DownloadString("http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?html5=1&video_id=sFwcLC5HC9I");
```

Comment: can't you just use https instead of http?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response you got indicates that HTTP is not supported for this API call. The next natural choice is HTTPS.

```
https://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?html5=1&video_id=sFwcLC5HC9I
```